# Apply Imagecache style to raw image url

Tags: 7, entities, media

I have a site I'm working on where images are inserted into the body of blog nodes and I'm wanting to return these images in a view. I'm using computed field to successfully return the url of the images in the view, but I would like to apply an imagecache style to this before displaying it using

```
<img src = "[computed_field]">
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this? I've been searching around and have not been able to successfully do this yet. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to refine your requirements. The "best way" depends on all your needs. For example, one solution here could be to use the `image_style_url` function in your computed field so that the image URL is already set to your desired style, however you've not specified whether you need the original URL as well.

Comment: Aha! I was trying something like that, but am a novice PHP coder. My computed field function currently looks like this `preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $entity->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], $matches);
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $matches['1']['0']; ` Any chance you can help me add in the `image_style_url` code to that function? For now I just cropped the images with CSS which works fairly well, but I'd love to wrap my head around this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See example in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should handle this in your computed field's PHP since you're already parsing out the image there.

```
//Assuming $entity is the parsed node in question 
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $entity->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'], $matches);

//If an image match has been found, build a URI relative to public file base
//Assume image URLs are something like:
// "/sites/default/my_files/some_dir/whatever.jpg"
if(isset($matches[1][0])) {
  $public_dir = variable_get('file_public_path','sites/default/files');
  $uri = file_build_uri(str_replace("/$public_dir/","",urldecode($matches[1][0])));
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = image_style_url('thumbnail',$uri);
}
```